# map json nested object from mongodb to java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, pojo

I'm getting json object on my mongodb with virustotal API 
This is how a json object stored in mongodb object looks like :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("597cd2f871eac714388b2f7f"),
"results" : {
    "scans" : {
        "Bkav" : {
            "detected" : true,
            "version" : "1.3.0.8042",
            "result" : "W32.HfsAutoB.971A",
            "update" : "20160706"
        },
        "TotalDefense" : {
            "detected" : false,
            "version" : "37.1.62.1",
            "result" : null,
            "update" : "20160706"
        },
        "MicroWorld-eScan" : {
            "detected" : true,
            "version" : "12.0.250.0",
            "result" : "Packer.Expressor.B",
            "update" : "20160706"
        },
        "nProtect" : {
            "detected" : true,
            "version" : "2016-07-06.01",
            "result" : "Packer.Expressor.B",
            "update" : "20160706"
        },
        "ALYac" : {
            "detected" : false,
            "version" : "1.0.1.9",
            "result" : null,
            "update" : "20160706"
        },           
        "TrendMicro" : {
            "detected" : true,
            "version" : "9.740.0.1012",
            "result" : "TROJ_GEN.R047C0CAP16",
            "update" : "20160706"
        },
        "McAfee-GW-Edition" : {
            "detected" : true,
            "version" : "v2015",
            "result" : "BehavesLike.Win32.Flyagent.cc",
            "update" : "20160706"
        },
        "Sophos" : {
            "detected" : true,
            "version" : "4.98.0",
            "result" : "W32/Pidgeon-A",
            "update" : "20160706"
        },
        "Cyren" : {
            "detected" : true,
            "version" : "5.4.16.7",
            "result" : "W32/SysVenFak.A.gen!Eldorado",
            "update" : "20160706"
        },
        "Microsoft" : {
            "detected" : true,
            "version" : "1.1.12902.0",
            "result" : "Backdoor:Win32/Delf.SJ",
            "update" : "20160706"
        },
        "AegisLab" : {
            "detected" : true,
            "version" : "4.2",
            "result" : "Backdoor.W32.BlackHole.acx!c",
            "update" : "20160706"
        },            
        "Qihoo-360" : {
            "detected" : false,
            "version" : "1.0.0.1120",
            "result" : null,
            "update" : "20160706"
        }
    },
    "scan_id" : "2ad6e0aad0b40f152f234787daa4afb87538f3278f5c8f815d53ef46d5eea4ac-1467833095",
    "sha1" : "c5dcd5526ac5330ad1e9fad51488718329fdb697",
    "resource" : "0a60424e0967b6cfc172dac82e10a2fe",
    "response_code" : 1,
    "scan_date" : "2016-07-06 19:24:55",
    "permalink" : "https://www.virustotal.com/file/2ad6e0aad0b40f152f234787daa4afb87538f3278f5c8f815d53ef46d5eea4ac/analysis/1467833095/",
    "verbose_msg" : "Scan finished, information embedded",
    "total" : 54,
    "positives" : 41,
    "sha256" : "2ad6e0aad0b40f152f234787daa4afb87538f3278f5c8f815d53ef46d5eea4ac",
    "md5" : "0a60424e0967b6cfc172dac82e10a2fe"
},
"response_code" : 200
}
```

As you can see the json object is too complicated to just get given value from, 
This is what i've tried so far :

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        MongoDatabase database1 = mongo.getDatabase(db);
        MongoCollection<Document> collection1 = database1.getCollection(col);
        try (MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection1.find().iterator()){

            while (cursor.hasNext()){
                Document doc = cursor.next();
                List list = new ArrayList(doc.values());
                System.out.println(list.get(1));
            }

        }
```

I was thinking maybe there is a way to map all this json to a java class, the main problem is with the `"scans"` as there are many different scannors and it isn't optimized to create a java class model to each of them, 
My question is how can i store directly my json objects to a java object so as to operate on the results returned.

Answer (score 1):

I am calling your main model as Scan. You can create a POJO (lets call it Scanner) with below attributes:
scannerName, detected, version, result, update;

Scanner.java

```
private String scannerName;
private String detected;
private String version;
private String result;
private String update;
```

Scan.java

```
private String scan_id;
private List<Scanner> = new ArrayList<Scanner>();
private String sha1;
private String resource;
......
........
```

So your scan model now has a List of scanners.

Using morphia its something like:

```
@Embedded
private List<Scanner> scanner;
```

If you are not using any wrapper around the java-driver, just try

```
private List<BasicDBObject>
```

Comment: i'm a little bit confuse with what you are suggesting, as i said there a lot of scanners, how is it possible to store each of them in a list, can you please provide an example, I can't seem to understand your answer, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two java classes in order to parse Json of coming from Mongo,Suppose First Class Name `"CollectionReceived"`
            Second Class Name `"Result"`
In CollectionReceived class you need to declare members

```
public String _id;
public String response_code;
public Result result;
```

In Result class you need to declare members

```
Map<String,Map<String,Map<String,Map<String,Object>>>> results=new HashMap<String,Map<String,Map<String,Map<String,Object>>>>();,
public String scan_id;
public String sha1;
public String resource;
public String response_code;
public String scan_date;
public String permalink;
public String verbose_msg;
public String total;
public String positives;
public String sha256;
public String md5;
```

and don't forget to use `@RestController` on your controller, You will parse Json Easily and get all the values you required.

Comment: I don't understand very well what you are trying to say, and why would I add `@RestController`

Comment: Suppose i want to get the `version` of `BKav`, how can i get that?

Comment: Bkav is the HashMap and you can get its value based on its key and in your case key is version

Comment: @RestController will parse your Json in to java object.

Comment: This is the annotation used in Spring boot if i'm not mistaken, i'm not working with that